# how to compare two array of objects to remove duplicates?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, duplicates

I am working with two array of objects to remove duplicates objects.

I have array1 of Class1.java

```
String name;
String number;
```

I added objects like below:

```
list1.add(new Class1("name1","number1"));
list1.add(new Class1("name2","number2"));
list1.add(new Class1("name3","number3"));
list1.add(new Class1("name4","number4"));

list2.add(new Class1("name1","number1"));
list2.add(new Class1("name5","number2"));
list2.add(new Class1("name6","number3"));
list2.add(new Class1("name2","number4"));
```

now I want to compare list1 and list 2 in the name basis. 
How can I remove duplicate elements from list1 after comparing with list 2.

Comment: Have you try to use HashSet?

Comment: I tried with single arraylist.

Comment: So you want to remove elements on list 1 that exists on list 2?

Comment: @JuanCarlosMendoza, yes

Answer (score 2):

You can remove elements in `list1` that exists on `list2` using the [removeAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#removeAll-java.util.Collection-) method. First you have to override the equals and hashCode methods in your class:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (!(o instanceof Class1)) return false;

    Class1 class1 = (Class1) o;

    return name.equals(class1.name);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return name.hashCode();
}
```

Then after adding the elements, just use the method `removeAll` like this:

```
list1.add(new Class1("name1","number1"));
list1.add(new Class1("name2","number2"));
list1.add(new Class1("name3","number3"));
list1.add(new Class1("name4","number4"));

list2.add(new Class1("name1","number1"));
list2.add(new Class1("name5","number2"));
list2.add(new Class1("name6","number3"));
list2.add(new Class1("name2","number4"));

list1.removeAll(list2);
```

`list1` after removing elements:

> [Class1{name='name3'}, Class1{name='name4'}]

**EDIT**

Another way without overriding `equals` and `hashCode` is using the [removeIf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-) method (available since java 8):

```
list1.removeIf(c -> list2.stream()
                    .map(Class1::getName)
                    .anyMatch(n -> n.equals(c.getName())));
```

Here I'm removing each element on `list1` whose name is equal to the name of an element on `list2`.

Comment: Cool. Now you can [accept this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) then.

Answer (score 0):

Combine both list into single list and send it below custom function :

[HashMap](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/HashMap.html) store unique key, Select any field(unique value) from own class and set that field value as key into HashMap and class object as value.

```
private List<Class1> clearListFromDuplicateFirstName(List<Class1> combineList) {

     Map<String, Class1> cleanMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, Class1>();
     for (int i = 0; i < combineList.size(); i++) {
          cleanMap.put(combineList.get(i).getname(), combineList.get(i));
     }

     return new ArrayList<Class1>(cleanMap.values());;
}
```